# Apigility and https

Tags: angularjs, rest, https, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools

I got a problem with apigility and https.
To enable https communication between AngularJs frontend and Apigility backend, I used this tutorial: 
http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords. Almost everything works fine, but REST webservices doesn't respond via https. 
When, using Advanced REST Client, I'm sending request e.g.

```
https://localhost:8888/status
```

NO RESPONSE appears. 
Does anyone know where might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For defiantly it is server fault. My apigility instances are working perfectly normal on production server with SSL. Could you give some more information.
Can you open your apiglity admin panel by browser? Is it working?

Is there any error in response headers or some other clue? Are you sending "Accept" header?

What is your apigility and zf2 versions?